# Problem with russian encoding when parsing javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

Here I am trying to parse my data but it has encoding mistake with question marks

```
    const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const i =1;
const parse = async () => {
    const getHTML = async (url) => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(url)
        return cheerio.load(data)
    }
    const selector = await getHTML('https://asu.edu.ru/universitet/5-kontaktnaia-informaciia.html')
    const selector_2 = await getHTML('https://asu.edu.ru/universitet/5-kontaktnaia-informaciia.html')
    
    selector('.container').each((i,element)  => {
        const title = selector(element).find('span').text();
        console.log(title);
    })

};
parse();
```

Comment: This site uses `windows-1251 ` encoding. `cheerio` has issues with non-UTF encodings.  You may want to replace it with `JSdom`.

Comment: @punund Cheerio shouldn't matter - isn't it Axios' responsibility to apply the proper decoding of the the request body?

Comment: I don't think that Axios cares about encodings. There is neither `iconv` nor `TextDecoder` mentions in its source. It seems that whoever responsibility this may be, we end up with it being developer's.